# help with finding user using directory service account management

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm having an issue when trying to pass the value into the method via a parameter (userName). If I hard code the value, it will find the user.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated,

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Text))
   {
      string userName = txtUserName.ToString();

      PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "car2.local", "DC=car2,DC=local");
      UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);

      if(usr != null)
      {
         lblStatus.Text = "user exists";
      }
      else
      {
         lblStatus.Text = "user does not exists";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am typing a value that matches a SAM Account Name. if i do this (ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "jason") it will find the user

Comment: Try using `string userName = txtUserName.Text.Trim();` instead - does that change anything??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - read out the `.Text` property of your textbox (and call `.Trim()` to get rid of any additional, superfluous whitespace) instead of using `.ToString()` on it:

```
string userName = txtUserName.Text.Trim();

UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);
```

If you don't specify what type of identity to search for - then AD will search for the most common identity types and hopefully find your user!

Comment: thank you for the help! my issue was using txt.UserName.ToString(); once i changed it to txt.UserName.Text.Trim(); it started working